# FAQ accordion show/hide

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently doing this FAQ beginner project and I need some help with the js code. How do I make it so that it only shows one answer at a time?

Here's the HTML/CSS:
https://github.com/Huy-jpg/faq-accordion-card-main

Here's the js code:

````
const containerQs = document.querySelectorAll('.detail-questions'),
      answers = document.querySelectorAll('.answers');

containerQs.forEach(container => {
  container.addEventListener('click', () => {
    answers.forEach(ans => {
      if(ans.classList.contains('active')){
        ans.classList.remove('active');
      } else{
        ans.classList.add('active');
      }
    })
  })
})```
````

Comment: in your css .answers{display: none}     .answer.active{dispaly: block}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are toggling the class on all `.answer` elements on each click.

You need to toggle it only in the next `<p>` element, see [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling).

I made [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4tmg321s/) to demonstrate.

The updated code:

```
const containerQs = document.querySelectorAll('.detail-questions');

containerQs.forEach(container => {
  container.addEventListener('click', () => {
      container.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('active');
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't used `display block inline`, because I need like a duration time when opening and closing.
I created a very simple accordion with a simple javascript code, I didn't focus on the css because you can put any css you want, our focus is on the javascript idea and a simple css code. use `height:0; transition: all 1s linear` in css than in Javascript you can change `height: 0` to the original height using `scrollHeight` in javascript, it gives you the main height of the element even if you in css put `height: 0`. If you have any question just ask me.
If you want I can edit your code with the same idea of my code.

```js
var opencloseques = document.getElementsByClassName("opencloseques");
    
for (let i = 0; i < opencloseques.length; i = i + 1) {
  opencloseques[i].onclick = function () {
    if (this.classList.contains("opened") == false) {
      this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("answer")[0].style.height = this.nextElementSibling.scrollHeight + "px";
      
      this.classList.add("opened")
    } else {
    this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("answer")[0].style.height = "0";
      this.classList.remove("opened")
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.questionanswer .answer {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="all">
    <div class="questionanswer">
        <button class="opencloseques">Click Me<span class='span'>+</span></button>
        <div class="answer">
            <p>Welcome To my website i hope you enjoy it Welcome To my website i hope you enjoy it Welcome To my website i hope you enjoy it Welcome To my website i hope you enjoy it Welcome To my website i hope you enjoy it Welcome To my website i hope you enjoy it </p>
        </div>
    </div>

     <div class="questionanswer">
        <button class="opencloseques">Click Me<span class='span'>+</span></button>
        <div class="answer">
            <p>Welcome To my website i hope you enjoy it Welcome To my website i hope you enjoy it Welcome To my website i hope you enjoy it Welcome To my website i hope you enjoy it Welcome To my website i hope you enjoy it Welcome To my website i hope you enjoy it </p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I've watched some tutorials that have the same idea as yours, but their codes are way more different than mine so I didn't know what I was doing. But this really helps, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome, If you have any other question just comment.

Comment: Accordion is very important, Nice chosen Idea